# Auto complete to show account details

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have a database which contains users, each user has an account number. I am trying to let users search for one another by using a Javascript autocomplete form field. (The user starts typing the other users account number to reveal a drop down of accounts.

Here is my drop down field

```
<label for="autocomplete">Select a programming language: </label>
<input id="autocomplete">

<script>
var tags = [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ];
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
          var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
          response( $.grep( tags, function( item ){
              return matcher.test( item );
          }) );
      }
});
</script>
```

My question is how do I display the users details below the form when the account number is selected?

Comment: None of your tags seemed relevant so I replaced them with some that do. If one of the language tags was relevant after all, please specify how so we can help more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the select option:

```
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#consumidor-autocomplete").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.getJSON("/consumidors.json?term=" + request.term, function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                        return {
                            label: value.nome,
                            value: value.nome,
                            id: value.id,
                            saldo: value.saldo,
                            operacao: value.operacao
                        };
                    }));
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var id = ui.item.id,
                    saldo = ui.item.saldo,
                    operacao = ui.item.operacao;
                $("#consumidor").val(id);
                $("#show-saldo").html("<span>Operação: " + operacao + "</span><br/><span>Saldo: R$ " + saldo + "</span>");

            }
        });
    });

};
```